# Error while using twitter cards

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter, handlebars.js, meta-tags, meta

I have implemented twitter cards, cards work, but all other pages crash  and only that particular page is rendered. 
 Card gets validated perfectly(even Image) however my web pages crash after using `<meta name="twitter:image" content="{{{cdnUrl events.banner_image}}}">`
Here is my code.

```
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary" />
<meta name="twitter:card" content="summary_large_image"/>
<meta name="twitter:site" content="@nytimes">
<meta name="twitter:creator" content="@SarahMaslinNir">
<meta name="twitter:title" content="{{{title}}}">
<meta name="twitter:description" content="{{{description}}}">
<meta name="twitter:image" content="{{{cdnUrl events.banner_image}}}">
```

I get error as `Cannot call method 'split' of undefined`. I tried to figure it out found that there is some glitch with twitter image code. If I remove it pages don't crash, but I need image for cards. Trying to get entities automatically.

Comment: What do you mean with *crash*?

Comment: @unor It shows up a blank screen with message "Cannot call method 'split' of undefined" for all the pages except the one being used cards.